# react-pdf & file-saver : Generating PDF From component and downloading results in corrupted files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, pdf, react-pdf

I am new to react. I am trying to save a component in pdf format. I looked around and tried multiple methods with react-pdf. However I have been unable to get the result so far. Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

I'll leave all relevant code here.

**Document Component**

```
import React from "react";
import { PDFViewer, Document, Page, Text, View, StyleSheet } from "@react-pdf/renderer";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    page: {
        flexDirection: "row",
        backgroundColor: "#E4E4E4",
    },
    section: {
        margin: 10,
        padding: 10,
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
});

export const ChallanPrint = (props: any) => {
    return (
        <Document> <Page size="A4" > <View ><Text> {JSON.stringify(props.pdfDocumentData)}</Text> </View> </Page> </Document>
    )
}
```

**Function to generate and save the PDF in Main Component**

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
import { pdf } from '@react-pdf/renderer';
const generatePdfDocument = async (documentData: any) => {
        const blob = await pdf((
            <ChallanPrint
                pdfDocumentData={challan}
            />
        )).toBlob();
        saveAs(blob, challan?.studentName+'-'+challan?.date+'.pdf');
    };
```

I'm calling this on an onClick in my main component `<button className="button" onClick={generatePdfDocument}>Print Challan</button><br></br>`

The Pdf file is downloaded with the correct name built from parameters but is corrupted and will not open. I have looked up reasons to what might be causing this but I haven't found anything relevant so far.

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the file to see what it contains?  Are you simply trying to print a JSON structure here?

Comment: @TimRoberts No, I have to structure the data but wanted to check if it works first. I have tried it with a simple Hello World string as well, same result. the JSON here is just an example.